what group is denoted by this?

I can't find a reference for this anywhere, it is from the sphinx cryptographic packet format https://www.freehaven.net/anonbib/cache/DBLP:conf/sp/DanezisG09.pdf.
x is used as a secret key in ECDH. I can understand Z but not the whole thing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a convential shorthand for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and the multiplication operator can be either 'x' or '*'

$Z_n$ is the group of integers $\pmod n$. ${Z^*}_n$ is the same without the $0$ element - i.e. it's just the multiplicative group. $\in_R$ means you randomly select $x$ from the group

The notation $x\in_R\mathbb Z_q^*$ (obtained as $x\in_R\mathbb Z_q^*$ in LaTex/MathJax) means that $x$ is a uniformly drawn random element of the multiplicative subgroup modulo $q$.
The multiplicative subgroup modulo $q$ is the subset of the integers modulo $q$ (often noted $\mathbb Z_q$ in a cryptographic context#) that are coprime to integer $q>1$, under the multiplicative law of the ring $(\mathbb Z_q,+,*)$. That second law can also be noted $\cdot$ or $\times$. It stands for multiplication modulo $q$.
One can think of the $*$ in $\mathbb Z_q^*$ as removing those elements of $\mathbb Z_q$ that are without inverse, including $0$, as in $\mathbb R^*$ versus $\mathbb R$. The $*$ can also be seen as a reminder that the group operation is multiplicative.
The set $\mathbb Z_q^*$ is a finite commutative group under multiplication modulo $q$. For example $\mathbb Z_{15}^*=\{1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14\}$ and the corresponding table of the group's law is
$$\begin{array}{r|rr}
*&1&2&4&7&8&11&13&14\\\hline
1&1&2&4&7&8&11&13&14\\
2&2&4&8&14&1&7&11&13\\
4&4&8&1&13&2&14&7&11\\
7&7&14&13&4&11&2&1&8\\
8&8&1&2&11&4&13&14&7\\
11&11&7&14&2&13&1&8&4\\
13&13&11&7&1&14&8&4&2\\
14&14&13&11&8&7&4&2&1
\end{array}$$
When $q$ is prime (which is typical in Diffie-Hellman), $\mathbb Z_q^*$ simply is the integers in the interval $[1,q-1]$.

# : Integers modulo $q$ are formally noted $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$, but are also noted $\mathbb Z_q$ when no confusion is possible with the p-adics.
